# An haskell "exp" function returns a wrong result

Tags: haskell

the following code:

```
Module Main where

main :: IO ()
main = do putStrLn "hello"
          putStrLn $ "2 exp 6 = " ++ show (2 `exp1` 6)

exp1 :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
exp1 x n | n == 0 = 1
         | n == 1 = x
         | even n =     exp1 (x*x) m
         | odd  n = x * exp1 (x*x) (m-1)
         where m = n `div` 2
```

produces the output `4` for `` 2 `exp1` 6 ``, which is obviously wrong.

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The odd case is wrong. You end up evaluating `exp1 4 3` to be `4 * (exp1 16 0)`.

Comment: Ok, I didn't tested but replace m-1 by m should work. Thanks